# Jupyter Notebook and pandas installation?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

currently i am doing course on Data Science on coursera but i dont know how to install jupyter notebook environment as well as pandas library can anyone show me how it is done?

Comment: `pip install jupyter pandas` if you have pip installed and then you would launch jupyter by `jupyter notebook` at the command line.

Answer (score 0):

1. I recommend you download & install [Anaconda Navigator](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/#)
2. Once you install & launch it, you can then download Jupyter notebook from the dashboard of anaconda navigator
3. If you want to create a new environment, say `new_env`, then there is an option for creating a new environment aswell. Just select if you want to use Python or R, and which version you want and a new environment is created
4. Assuming you are using windows, search for `Anaconda Prompt` from the windows start and activate the `new_env` by doing: `activate new_env`
5. When the `new_env` is activated, just follow the instructions [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/install.html) for installing pandas

You can also check this like out: [Installing Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)

Answer (score 0):

For fulfilling above requirement please install **Anaconda**(data science toolkit) in you system which comes with all the packages/modules which includes Pandas,Numpy and Jupyter notebook.

Anaconda comes with follow packages check out the [link](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/old-pkg-lists/4.3.1/py35/)

Anaconda Download [Link](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/)

How to install Video Guide [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_H4e4mmGAZw)